# faces bevel in different directions

Tags: vertices, faces, bevel, vertex-groups

the issues is the vertices locations are different so when I bevel it goes really bad [image]

like this :
[image]

every face goes in it's own direction

[image]

so how can I change the vertices direction

also the faces have different directions
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on face orientation overlay:

[image]

These polygons should have different direction. To fix that, select all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

If it doesn't help, you have [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry). In this case, flip faces manually by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> → Flip normals

Comment: thanks a lot man the shift N trick worked like a charm